# Which is better Comet or AJAX in term of 10->15 second polling?

Tags: php, ajax, apache, comet, polling

My site almost done but i have a problem. Every 10->15 seconds my site will search the database to check whether there are updates or not. If there are updates then send a notification to user who online.
I search google and found two solutions: Comet and AJAX. Which is better in my case. or is there a better solution?

Comment: I'd suggest your options are 1) AJAX polling 2) self hosted realtime solution (Comet/WebSockets) (but that depends on your hosting 3) Off load to a hosted realtime service (Comet/WebSockets). What is your hosting solution? Self-hosted full 'root' access? Or shared hosting? Since your using PHP and Apache it's likely that a self hosted realtime solution isn't going to be possible due to the requirement of maintaining many persistent connections. If you could clarify I'll suggest a solution.

Comment: I do not know much about web hosting but it's kind of shared hosting, they name it business hosting. My site use php and jquery therefore i think comet and ajax are quite suitable for me, but i read enormous comments they said that implement comet with php is not a good choice, you need use socket.io or node.js. Do you agree with them and what your opinion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion the best solution for a website that is on shared hosting and uses Apache and PHP is to use a [realtime hosted service](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide#hosted-services) to push updates to connected clients.

Here's why:

Apache wasn't built to handle long-running persistent connections so it's not a great choice for Comet or WebSocket solutions. The PHP Comet and WebSocket solutions that you'll find will likely run standalone as a daemon process and not on Apache. On shared hosting it's highly unlikely you'll be able to run a daemon process and your hosting provider is also unlikely to be happy with you keeping many persistent connections open and hogging resource on the shared machine.

If you got with an AJAX polling solution and poll your site every 10 to 15 seconds, and include a database query within that poll, then if you have a reasonable number of clients on your site resource usage can spike really quickly:

100 clients, 10 second polling, 60 second period = 100 * 10 * 6 = 6000 requests and database queries per minute. A lot of the time these requests may also be a waste if no update has occurred. You can find a larger example [here](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/pusher/pusher-presentations/why_use_pusher.html#13).

By offloading the ability to push updates instantly to your website clients you remove these 6000 requests and database queries and replace them with one call to the realtime hosted service. The service maintains the persistent connections to the clients so that when your application pushes the update to it, it can deliver them to the connected clients.

Finally, you should be aware that WebSockets supersede Comet as the preferred solution for realtime communication. The protocol was created to solve the problem that Comet solutions tried to solve with various hacks. For more on the history of these technologies and WebSockets see [here](http://pusher.com/websockets).